# Checking if TWO SSE registers are not both zero without destroying them

Tags: performance, optimization, assembly, sse, simd

I want to test if two *SSE* registers are not both zero without destroying them.

This is the code I currently have:

```
uint8_t *src;  // Assume it is initialized and 16-byte aligned
__m128i xmm0, xmm1, xmm2;

xmm0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)&src[i]); // Need to preserve xmm0 & xmm1
xmm1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)&src[i+16]);
xmm2 = _mm_or_si128(xmm0, xmm1);
if (!_mm_testz_si128(xmm2, xmm2)) { // Test both are not zero
}
```

Is this the best way (using up to SSE 4.2)?

Comment: What better can you hope ? At best sparing the OR.

Comment: I would have used `_mm_movemask_epi8` instead of `_mm_testz_si128` but actually `_mm_testz_si128` is better in general. `_mm_movemask_epi8` has a lower latency only on Nahalem and Westmere. But it's worse on Haswell. But more importantly is that it does not set the zero or carry flag in the FLAGS register but `_mm_testz_si128` does. So what you have now is probably best.

Comment: Actually this was the type of discussion I was looking for.  I would mark it as the answer but it's a comment.

Comment: Why does this question have two down-votes, I wonder ? It looks like a pretty decent question to me.

Comment: I wondered if PTEST could do something useful with two different unknown operands.  [I posted a Q&A with my results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712243/can-ptest-be-used-to-test-if-two-registers-are-both-zero-or-some-other-condition/43712244#43712244).  (TL:DR, no, you have to OR your data down to one register and PTEST same,same for this kind of problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned something useful from this question.  Let's first look at some scalar code

```
extern foo2(int x, int y);
void foo(int x, int y) {
    if((x || y)!=0) foo2(x,y);
}
```

Compile this like this `gcc -O3 -S -masm=intel test.c` and the important assembly is

```
 mov       eax, edi   ; edi = x, esi = y -> copy x into eax
 or        eax, esi   ; eax = x | y and set zero flag in FLAGS if zero
 jne       .L4        ; jump not zero
```

Now let's look at testing SIMD registers for zero. Unlike scalar code there is no SIMD FLAGS register. However, with SSE4.1 there are SIMD test instructions which can set the zero flag (and carry flag) in the scalar FLAGS register.

```
extern foo2(__m128i x, __m128i y);
void foo(__m128i x, __m128i y) {
    __m128i z = _mm_or_si128(x,y);
    if (!_mm_testz_si128(z,z)) foo2(x,y);
}
```

Compile with `c99 -msse4.1 -O3 -masm=intel -S test_SSE.c` and the the important assembly is

```
movdqa      xmm2, xmm0 ; xmm0 = x, xmm1 = y, copy x into xmm2
por         xmm2, xmm1 ; xmm2 = x | y
ptest       xmm2, xmm2 ; set zero flag if zero
jne         .L4        ; jump not zero
```

Notice that this takes one more instruction because the packed bit-wise OR does not set the zero flag. Notice also that both the scalar version and the SIMD version need to use an additional register (`eax` in the scalar case and `xmm2` in the SIMD case). <s>**So to answer your question your current solution is the best you can do.**</s>

<s>However, if you did not have a processor with SSE4.1 or better you would have to use `_mm_movemask_epi8`.</s> Another alternative which only needs SSE2 is to use `_mm_movemask_epi8`

```
extern foo2(__m128i x, __m128i y);
void foo(__m128i x, __m128i y) {
    if (_mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_or_si128(x,y))) foo2(x,y);   
}
```

The important assembly is

```
movdqa      xmm2, xmm0
por         xmm2, xmm1
pmovmskb    eax, xmm2
test        eax, eax
jne         .L4
```

Notice that this needs one more instruction then with the SSE4.1 `ptest` instruction.

Until now I have been using the `pmovmaskb` instruction because the latency is better on pre Sandy Bridge processors than with `ptest`. However, I realized this before Haswell. On Haswell the latency of `pmovmaskb` is worse than the latency of `ptest`. They both have the same throughput. But in this case this is not really important. What's important (which I did not realize before) is that `pmovmaskb` does not set the FLAGS register and so it requires another instruction. **So now I'll be using `ptest` in my critical loop.** Thank you for your question.

Edit: as suggested by the OP there is a way this can be done without using another SSE register.

```
extern foo2(__m128i x, __m128i y);
void foo(__m128i x, __m128i y) {
    if (_mm_movemask_epi8(x) | _mm_movemask_epi8(y)) foo2(x,y);    
}
```

The relevant assembly from GCC is:

```
pmovmskb    eax, xmm0
pmovmskb    edx, xmm1
or          edx, eax
jne         .L4
```

Instead of using another xmm register this uses two scalar registers.

Note that fewer instructions does not necessarily mean better performance. Which of these solutions is best? You have to test each of them to find out.

Comment: How about if (_movemask_epi8(x)|_movemask_epi8(y))?  Wouldn't that create two movemskb and one 'or' command(s) - for a total of 3?

Comment: @ChipK, you're totally right (see my updated answer). Looks like you answered your own question. It's is possible to do this without using another XMM register.

Comment: The `pmovmskb` portion of this answer is bogus.  You're only testing the sign bits: the result doesn't depend on bits 0..6 of any of the bytes!  `por` / `ptest` / `jnz` is a pretty good choice.  The other way is [the same number of uops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989897/is-an-m128i-variable-zero/7991083#comment59454214_35890766). `por` / `pcmpeqb` (against all-zero) / `pmovmskb` / `test/jnz`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use C / C ++, you can not control the individual CPU registers. If you want full control, you must use assembler.

Comment: Right, the compiler is free to allocate registers his way.