# Most efficient way to check if all __m128i components are 0 [using <= SSE4.1 intrinsics]

Tags: c++, integer, sse, simd, intrinsics

I am using SSE intrinsics to determine if a rectangle (defined by four `int32` values) has changed:

```
__m128i oldRect; // contains old left, top, right, bottom packed to 128 bits
__m128i newRect; // contains new left, top, right, bottom packed to 128 bits

__m128i xor = _mm_xor_si128(oldRect, newRect);
```

At this point, the resulting `xor` value will be all zeros if the rectangle hasn't changed. What is then the most efficient way of determining that?

Currently I am doing so:

```
if (xor.m128i_u64[0] | xor.m128i_u64[1])
{
    // rectangle changed
}
```

But I assume there's a smarter way (possibly using some SSE instruction that I haven't found yet).

I am targeting SSE4.1 on x64 and I am coding C++ in Visual Studio 2013.

*Edit: The question is not quite the same as [Is an __m128i variable zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989897/is-an-m128i-variable-zero), as that specifies "on SSE-2-and-earlier processors" (although Antonio did add an answer "for completeness" that addresses 4.1 some time after this question was posted and answered).*

Comment: Why are you referring to a 128-bit integer value as `NULL`, which is a null *pointer* constant?

Comment: @KeithThompson `NULL` is a macro that expands to 0. C++ has `nullptr` as the null pointer constant.

Comment: `NULL` expands to an implementations defined C++ null pointer constant. It *could* expand to `nullptr`. Even if it happens to expand to `0`, it shouldn't be used as an integer.

Comment: @KeithThompson To quote Bjarne Stroustrup: "In C++, the definition of NULL is 0, so there is only an aesthetic difference. A problem with NULL is that people sometimes mistakenly believe that it is different from 0 and/or not an integer. In pre-standard code, NULL was/is sometimes defined to something unsuitable and therefore had/has to be avoided. That's less common these days."

Comment: Stroustrup is talking about using `NULL` or `0` as a null pointer constant. He doesn't advocate using `NULL` as an integer constant. Why would you write `NULL` rather than `0` anyway? In addition to style issues, `NULL` may legally be defined as `nullptr`, which is not an integer expression.

Comment: @KeithThompson No, he isn't: "..people sometimes mistakenly believe that [NULL] is different from 0 and/or not an integer." NULL is the SAME as writing 0.

Comment: @KeithThompson And the reason I chose `NULL` in the question title was because it is more discernible than a `0` there, it being the whole purpose of the question. I also wanted to hint at the fact that checking if an `__m128i` is `all zeros` is not as simple as just comparing it to a regular integer value.

Comment: `NULL` is for pointers -- and a null pointer is not necessarily all-bits-zero. I understand that you want something distinct from the `int` constant `0`, but `NULL` is confusing and potentially incorrect. How about the English word "zero"?

Comment: @KeithThompson What part of this are you not getting? NULL is SYNONYMOUS with 0, the integer. http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null

Comment: Stroustrup refers to C++11 in the future tense. It's now the standard, and it says that `NULL` may be defined as `nullptr`, which is not an integer expression. Stroustrup's FAQ doesn't define the language; the standard does. In any case, `NULL` is and always has been intended to be used as a *pointer* value. Is `__m128i` a pointer type?

Comment: @KeithThompson From MSDN: "Avoid using NULL or zero (0) as a null pointer constant". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651642.aspx

Comment: @KeithThompson From the Standard: "Should I use NULL or 0 or nullptr? You should use `nullptr` as the null pointer value. The others still work for backward compatibility with older code."
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#null-or-zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68668/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-d7samurai).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an \_\_m128i variable zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989897/is-an-m128i-variable-zero)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the PTEST instuction via the [_mm_testz_si128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514073.aspx) intrinsic (SSE4.1), like this:

```
#include "smmintrin.h" // SSE4.1 header

if (!_mm_testz_si128(xor, xor))
{
    // rectangle has changed
}
```

Note that `_mm_testz_si128` returns 1 if the bitwise `AND` of the two arguments is zero.

Answer (score 7):

Ironically, `ptest` instruction from SSE 4.1 may be slower than `pmovmskb` from SSE2 in some cases. I suggest using simply:

```
__m128i cmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(oldRect, newRect);
if (_mm_movemask_epi8(cmp) != 0xFFFF)
  //registers are different
```

Note that if you really need that `xor` value, you'll have to compute it separately.

For Intel processors like Ivy Bridge, the version by PaulR with `xor` and `_mm_testz_si128` translates into 4 uops, while suggested version without computing `xor` translates into 3 uops (see also [this thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/293050)). This may result in better throughput of my version.

Comment: Is this extra latency still a problem on Haswell ? I guess I should write some benchmark code and check it...

Comment: @PaulR: I don't get which latency you are talking about. I usually look only at throughput, because latency is much harder to analyze and measure =(
And here "slower" is also in sense of throughput, not latency. In some cases throughput of vectorized code is limited by frontend, which can process only a limited number of uops per cycle. So in these cases: more uops = slower throughput.

Comment: @stgatilov: I was referring to the thread you linked to where it says, e.g. "PTEST is decoded into 2 uops and has 3 cycle latency when receives sources from FP instruction", but I guess my question also applies to µops - is the situation the same on Haswell/Skylake ?

Comment: The intel thread seems to now be at: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-ISA-Extensions/PTEST-improvement/m-p/877818